# Does $f^{-1}[C] \subseteq f^{-1}[D] \implies C \subseteq D$?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I know that $C \subseteq D \implies f^{-1}[C] \subseteq f^{-1}[D]$, but I was wondering if the converse is true? The only thing I can think of is that some element outside  of $D$ maps to an element inside of $f[D]$, and when you take the pre-image you chose that point that is outside of $D$. So my intuition would say that the converse is false, but I would like some advice on this.

Comment: By converse, do you mean the second containment is true for all functions or just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the unique function $\emptyset \to \{1,2\}$ and $C:= \{1\}, D:= \{2\}$. Then
$$f^{-1}(C) = f^{-1}(D) = \emptyset$$ yet $C \not\subseteq D$.

You can make less extreme counterexamples by just taking disjoint sets $C,D$ outside the image of your function.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a constant function $f$ and choose $D$ so that it has more than $2$ elements. If $f(c)$ is always equal to $a\in D$ and if $b,c\in D$ are distinct from each other and distinct from $a$, then $f^{-1}(\{b\})=f^{-1}(\{c\})=\emptyset$. But $\{c\}\not\subset\{d\}$ and $\{d\}\not\subset\{c\}$.